# Why cannot ImageGrab.grab capture the whole screen?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, screenshot

I was trying to capture my screen image using PIL.ImageGrab.grab().
Here is my problem -- When I use the code below, `img` is only the upper left part of my screen.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
img = ImageGrab.grab()
```

Use `win32api.GetSystemMetrics()` to find out my screen size.

```
> GetSystemMetrics(0)
Out[6]: 1280

> GetSystemMetrics(1)
Out[7]: 720
```

I then used `ImageGrab.grab((0,0,1280,720))`, and still got the upper left part of my screen! Desperately, I called `ImageGrab.grab((0,0,1400,900))`, and the output is the same partial image with a black frame in its lower right area...

I have no idea what happened. It seems other guys are able to capture their screen by simply call `ImageGrab.grab()`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: By the way, I'm using python3.5 on WIN10, and all operation above are performed on an Dell-XPS laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem on PIL when I was trying to follow this tutorial https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-python-bot-that-can-play-web-games--active-11117.

To solve this problem,

**->** Goto Python installed directory and Right-click on python.exe

**->** Properties **->** Compatibility tab **->** check 'Disable display scaling on high DPI settings'.

Repeat the same procedure for pythonw.exe. Hope your problem solved. Please let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! U really help me out!

Comment: By the way, 'Disable display scaling on high DPI settings' is now replaced with ''Override high-DPI scaling behavior'.

Answer (score 3):

As [josh pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42036701), `There is a working workaround for this without fiddling with the OS settings. The solution is to use the following to make your program DPI aware on Windows:`

```
from ctypes import windll
user32 = windll.user32
user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
```

by [josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7187939/josh)