# PyAutoGui uses a scaled resolution of my screen for functions (MacOS)

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm running on Macbook and my issue is that functions like pyautogui.moveTo use a coordinate system of 1440,900 when my screen size is 2560,1600)

This is a problem because other commands like pyautogui.pixel use the real screen size (2560,1600) so the too commands aren't in sync

Comment: This seems to be a problem similar to yours, might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24815404/14178515

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this problem by using scaling.

take the position you want to click and multiply its x and y - coordinates by the scaling factor (for example: on a macbook pro retina this is 0.5).

```py
scaling = 0.5 # any scaling factor you wish
position = (1200, 1500) # the coordinates where you want to move to

x, y = position
x *= scaling 
y *= scaling
```

and then, as usual:

```py
moveTo(x, y)
```